# Merge and Sort JSON using JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have a file containing the following structure and unknown number of results:

```
{
"results": [
      [
         {
            "field": "AccountID",
            "value": "5177497"
         },
         {
            "field": "Requests",
            "value": "50900"
         }
      ],
      [
         {
            "field": "AccountID",
            "value": "pro"
         },
         {
            "field": "Requests",
            "value": "251"
         }
      ]
   ],
   "statistics": {
      "Matched": 51498,
      "Scanned": 8673577,
      "ScannedByte": 2.72400814E10
   },
   "status": "HOLD"
}
{
"results": [
      [
         {
            "field": "AccountID",
            "value": "5577497"
         },
         {
            "field": "Requests",
            "value": "51900"
         }
      ],
   "statistics": {
      "Matched": 51498,
      "Scanned": 8673577,
      "ScannedByte": 2.72400814E10
   },
   "status": "HOLD"
}
```

There are multiple such results which are indexed as an array with the results folder. They are not seperated by a comma.

I am trying to just print The "AccountID" sorted by "Requests" in ZSH using jq. I have tried flattening them and using:

jq -r '.results[][0] |.value ' filename

jq -r '.results[][1] |.value ' filename

To get the Account ID and Requests seperately and sorting them. I don't think bash has a dictionary that can be used. The problem lies in the file as the Field and value are not key value pair but are both pairs. Therefore extracting them using the above two lines into seperate arrays and sorting by the second array seems a bit too long. I was wondering if there is a way to combine both the operations. 
The other way is to combine it all to a string and sort it in ascending order. Python would probably have the best solution but the code requires to be a zsh or bash script.

Solutions that use sed, jq or any other ZSH supported compilers are welcome. If there is a way to create a dictionary in bash, please do let me know.

The projectd output requirement is just the Account ID vs Request Number.

```
5577497 has 51900 requests
5177497 has 50900 requests
pro has 251 requests
```

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.  Since the file includes a stream of JSON objects, it would make sense to provide a sample with two such objects.  If it helps, it's ok to include both a (small) valid sample together with an indicative illustration that may not be a valid stream of valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind learning a little jq, it will probably be best to write a small jq program to do what you want.

To get you started, consider the following jq program, which assumes your input is a stream of valid JSON objects with a "results" key similar to your sample:

```
[inputs | .results[] | map( { (.field) : .value} ) | add]
```

After making minor changes to your input so that it consists of valid JSON objects, an invocation of jq with the -n option produces an array of AccountID/Requests objects:

```
[
  {
    "AccountID": "5177497",
    "Requests": "50900"
  },
  {
    "AccountID": "pro",
    "Requests": "251"
  },
  {
    "AccountID": "5577497",
    "Requests": "51900"
  }
]
```

You could (for example) now use jq's `group_by` to group these objects by AccountID, and thereby produce the result you want.

Comment: What I had already done with JQ did the same thing. But with your command. I can do it one step.

```list=$(jq -r '.results[] | map( { (.field) : .value} ) | add ' query-results-aggregate)```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
jq -S '.results[] | map( { (.field) : .value} ) | add' query-results-aggregate \
  | jq -s -c 'group_by(.number_of_requests) | .[]'
```

This does the trick. Thanks to peak for the guidance.

Comment: There is no need to invoke jq twice!